# Unable to import 'flask_wtf' & 'wtforms' in a virtual env even though I've already pip installed them?

Tags: python, virtualenv

So I'm running a virtual python environment and I was learning flask. Everything was going good until I got to learning about forms. I pip installed `Flask-WTF` in the console (just as I had done with Flask) except when I went to type my code I saw that neither `flask_wtf` or  `wtforms` could be imported. Here's my code:

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import BooleanField, PasswordField, StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')
```

I get errors on lines 1 - 3 for all of the imports. Here's my `FlaskProject` (top-level) directory:

[Flask Project Top-Level Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwxts.png)

Here are all the modules I have installed:

[Flask Project Installed Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdIeQ.png)

I'm really not sure what's causing these errors.

EDIT: I also think it's worth noting that I'm not getting errors when importing other modules such as flask. In case anyone asks, here are the versions of the modules I currently have installed:

[Installed Modules w/ Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEdIP.png)

EDIT2: I'm running Python 3.7

EDIT3: These are the only two things I can't seem to import

EDIT4: I've actually solved this and I have no idea why but VSCode was marking these items as unable to import when they were, in fact, importing perfectly fine. Anyways, thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Are you running the Flask app after activating the `venv`? If you have not set project interpreter, Pycharm will not use virtual environment. Please remove the image URLs with actual images and include `pip freeze` output.

Comment: @arsho Yeah I'm running it after. I'm also not using Pycharm (I'm using VSCode). The final image is the `pip freeze` output.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can't see these modules because you've installed them from another virtual environment.
Can you tell what is the output when you execute the command pip list?
If there are no modules flask_wtf and wtfforms, you have to activate your virtualenv where are those modules installed.
Activate virtualenv using the command:

```
Windows - source venv/scripts/activate
Linux - source venv/bin/activate
```

And after that, if you don't have any of these modules already installed, install them using command pip install name_of_module.

Comment: When I run `pip list` I get a list of all the modules installed including Flask-WTF and WTForms both at their latest versions.

Comment: Open command line and go to the your project(directory where app and venv are installed). For example cd /absolute path of your project/ and run command source venv/scripts/activate and then run command pip list and send what is output of these two commands.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode was marking the imports as an `import-error` when there was no actual error. Very weird but everything imported perfectly fine.